# Ambient Occlusion artifacts

Tags: texturing, uv

I faced with problem while baking Ambient Occlusion map. There are a lot of artifacts in border zone between two objects. I try to change different parameters like distance/margin/samples but nothing works. The same result. Does anyone know the cure?[image]

Comment: Bake your AO maps in higher resolution, then downscale them. AO bake won't give AA on intersecting faces.

Comment: You probably just need to use a larger target texture. In image editor you can create a new, larger texture.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny, thanks for respond. As far as I understand, you mean the next: scale 'problem' object to whole UV, save resulted baked AO image, then open it in any graphical redactor, decrease it's size, and then open it again in Blender, then scale down corresponding UV to decreased picture? What means "AA"?

Comment: @Danil you don't have to do anything with UVs, just bake to higher resolution image(like 4 times the resolution). Then save the image and use Gimp, Krita, Photoshop or even Blender to scale it down to original resolution. AA means anti-aliasing, what you have are aliasing artifacts.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny, great thanks for help! Now it looks much better. I bake texture at 10240 px, then donwscale it to normal texture size 2048 px, then upload to Blender.

Comment: @TaviKohn, thanks for advise. It is possible solution and it gives pretty fine result, but I'd plan to make one texture for joined to one object. Because it is more easy to work with one texture, than with many.